# How to create custom menu in oracle UCM 10gR3 using nav builder

Tags: oracle-ucm

I want to create a component which will add custom menu in oracle UCM 10gR3. As of now such component is possible using oracle UCM 11g,so I tried to implement the same in oracle UCM 10gR3.
 This is resource.htm file of component 'custommenu' that I have created

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>
custommenu htmlIncludeOrString
</title>
</head>
<body>

<@dynamichtml custommenuSampleTable@>
<?commatable indexedColumn="sampleKey"  
 countColumn="sampleCount"sortCloumn="sampleOrder"
sampleKey,sampleValue,sampleOrder,sampleCount
key2,  value2, 20
key1,  value1, 10
<@end@>

<@dynamichtml coreMenuItems@>
id,label,linkType,linkData
custommenu1,my first menu,.
custom menu2,my second menu,.
custommenu,Sub Menu,.
THING_1,Get Server Output,cgi,IdcService=GET_SERVER_OUTPUT
THING_2,My Document,cgi,Idc=GET_SEARCH_RESULT&QueryText=%  
28dDocAuthor+<contains>+%60<$UserName$>
THING_3,Component Manager,admin,IdcService=GET_COMPONENT_DATA
<@end@>

<@dynamichtml CoreMenuItemRelationship@>
<?commatable mergeKey="primaryKey"?>
parentid,id,loadorder
MENU_A,custommenu1,500
MENU_B,custommenu2,500
custommenu1,THING_1,10
custommenu1,THING_2,20
custommenu1,THING_3,30
<@end@>


</body></html>
```

but when we enable this component no change is found in UCM.
All kind of views are invited.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code only works in 11g. See [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/modifying_navigation_menus_in_ucm) for more info.

You need to use a method available in 10g. Here are some examples:

- https://hishamgalal.blogspot.com/2009/02/deleting-and-adding-menu-items.html
- https://bungbutan.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/oracle-webcenter-content-grouping-menu-items-into-one-new-menu/
- https://oramack.blogspot.com/2010/04/ucm-modify-check-in-menu.html
- http://blogs.redstonecontentsolutions.com/technical-blog/alphabetizemenus-11g (shows difference between 10g and 11g)